# jsPDF not ignoring div

Tags: jquery, html, jspdf

I am trying to ignore a div while exporting to pdf via jsPDF.
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="print-this">
<p>Text to print</p>
  <div id="ignore">
    <p>Text To ignore</p>
  </div>
<p>More text to print</p>
</div>
<button id="cmd">Print</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {

  $('#cmd').click(function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var elementHandler = {
  '#ignore': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
    doc.addHTML($('#print-this')[0], 15, 15, {
      'background': '#fff',
    }, function() {
      doc.save('sample.pdf');
    });
  });
});
```

Instead of ignoring a specific id it is exporting everything under id="print-this".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super dirty but does the trick:

```
$(function() {
  $('#cmd').click(function() {
    $('#ignore').hide(); //before the addHTML()
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addHTML($('#print-this')[0], 15, 15, {
      'background': '#fff',
    }, function() {
      doc.save('sample.pdf');
    });
    $('#ignore').show(); //and directly after its finished
  });
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bu9db10d/218/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btnPrint").click(function () {
    $(".canhide").hide();

    makePDF();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".canhide").show(); 
    }, 5000);
});
```

I had a problem, while generating multiple pages,as simple  `$(".canhide").show();`after `makePDF()` does not hide the unnecessary content. `setTimeout` function saved me.